# range to width of window in QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I am new to `QPainter` and So, my question is to how to set specific range for the y-axis. for example, my window size is 600 * 600, and I want the 600 in the y-axis or the width to be ranged from 0 to 60,000 for example with step 1000 between each two pixels. I know in default this range is from 0-600 but I wonder if there is any way I could change this range.

Comment: In the end you are wanting that each pixel is divided into 500 parts, but by definition a pixel is the minimum unit of image, so it can not be divided.

Comment: you are right. thank you. I am able to deal with them carefully now....

Comment: In addition to @eyllanesc: From [`QPainter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#details): _Normally, it draws in a "natural" coordinate system, but it can also do view and world transformation._ With the appropriate scaling, values from 0 to 60000 can be used in the draw functions. I've to admit that I once played a bit with scaling and observed that scaling is also applied to things like pen width (which may or may not be intended). (Regarding pen width, pen width 0 might help to prevent scaling of line width - I've not yet tried this.)